# ChartJSNodeCanvas Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js, fontconfig

Im having an issue

Im currently trying to run a javascript project with ChartJSNodeCanvas

```
  const width = 400; //px
    const height = 400; //px
    const canvasRenderService = new ChartJSNodeCanvas({width:width, height:height});
    const configuration = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: ['Team Points'],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: `Team Red: ${points.red.points}`,
              borderColor: "#000000",
              backgroundColor:"#f55442",
              data: [points.red.points],
            },
            {
                label: `Team Blue: ${points.blue.points}`,
                borderColor: "#000000",
                backgroundColor: "#3450e0",
                data: [points.blue.points],
            },
          ],
        },}
```

This code works fine on windows but in my cloud enviorment it will result in missing characters

It gives me the following error: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file

How do I fix this ?